# PWA, Service Worker error: "Internet connection appears to be offline"

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a progressive web app that works offline, but sometimes when I'm offline and I'm not inside of the 'bookmark' and I open it, I get a white screen with the error: `"Safari cannot open the page. The error was: "FetchEvent.respondWith received an error: TypeError: The Internet connection appears to be offline."`

I suppose this is coming from the "Fetch" event on the service worker, and this is my code:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  const {
    request,
    request: {
      url,
      method,
    },
  } = event;
  if (event.request.url.startsWith(self.location.origin)) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request)
      .catch(function(error){
        return;
      })
      .then(function (res) {
        if (event.request.method == 'POST' && !navigator.onLine) { //Prevent POST since they give errors.
          if (res != 'undefined') {
            return res;
          }
          return fetch(event.request);
        } else {
          return fetchAndUpdate(event.request);
        }
      })
    );
  }else{
    return;
  }
})
```

Am I missing something or am I looking at the wrong place? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: did you find a solution? of course everything is working except with Apple sh**